# How can I repeat the tutorial?

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-online

I mistakenly skipped the tutorial and now I can't join my friend. I know there is a workaround by using social club invites but I think that I have to play the tutorial. I'm on PC btw.

Comment: Btw. question is pretty self explanatory.

Comment: You don't have to complete the tutorial to play with your friend, you can add them to your social club and they will appear on the "friends" tab in your start menu. Simply navigate to your friend on the list and select them and then choose "invite to game" this should sort things out!

Comment: @JonHick "I know there is a workaround by using social club invites but I think that I have to play the tutorial." I do know it but people from the last job can't invite me too.

Comment: Is this; PC, PS4, Xbox1, Xbox360, Ps3?

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ PC, I edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure if this was the cause (can't test it as I already did the tutorial) but:

I created a new character, then I completed the tutorial with it. Right after that I returned to my old/original character. After a while on my original/old character, I saw that I was able to invite my friends using the in-game menu.

Comment: Yeah yeah I know, not that explanatory nor tested much. Please test before downvote rain and let us know.

Answer (score 1):

The process JonHick describes in his comment is not a 'workaround', it's the usual process:

To play with friends, go to the Social Club (HOME key on PC by default) and add your friend to your friends list. Now you have two options to play together:

- In the friends list, choose the 'join' option to go to their session
- Start an activity and use the interface there to 'invite from friend list' (then either 'invite all online friends' or 'Select from list of online friends').

Comment: Another question, sorry, I know people don't like to see that in the comments, but how can i invite someone to a mission? I was struggling with that yesterday after me and my brother were bored of shooting innocent civilians or fresh spawned people.

Comment: Once you've joined a mission yourself, either as the host or as one of the players, you should have the option to invite people. If you are the host and you want to make 100% sure your friend is in there with you, make the session *Private* at first, invite your friend, and then open it up to public and start inviting other people.

Comment: I tried this several times, but when i do so, there is a little field which says "blocked" after i invited my friend.

Comment: @YUNOWORK Matchmaking:Off Auto-Invite:On Try this.

Comment: This does not answer the question, unfortunately. (Does not provide a way to repeat the tutorial).

Comment: That's because there is no way to repeat the tutorial for this character, although you *could* try starting a new character.